# paintcomponent in paint program throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, paintcomponent, repaint

I am making project on JFrame and adding JPanel on JFrame. When I am using paintcomponents function it is throwing `NullPointerException`. What can I do?

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.paintComponents(g);
        if(OSC==null)
        {
            createOSC();
        }

        g.drawImage(OSC, 0, 0, null);

        if(dragging&&SHAPE_TOOLS.contains(currentTool))
        {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            putCurrentShape(g);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace ?